# Applications of laws of Physics

Tags: resource-recommendations, applied-physics

The problem i always suffered was that all the texts books of Physics although states the laws of physics but they never tell about the applications of these laws in daily life. Many students like me spend their time in memorizing the laws of Physics stated in the text books but they hardly come to know that what is the usefulness of these laws, how we can use them, for what purpose they are stated. May be many people here have different and better academic experience. Can anyone one tell me about any book that concentrates more on the applications of the laws of physics so that a high school or a college reader may understand physics better?

Comment: Application of physical laws is called "engineering", "material science", "industrial chemistry" etc.. There are vast amounts of material for any of these fields, but it's not something that physicists care much about. Apart from that the subject would fill libraries, so your question is way too broad.

Comment: Also, memorizing mathematics and physics is a really bad habit. It's way better if you understand it, it takes a lot less of your mental resources and you can apply the reasoning to new, unseen situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think every textbooks describe a little on the application of a law or theory. Because most theories of physics were developed to explain some physical phenomena or understanding our surrounding better. Generally, a textbook can't go deep to any theory because of its limited size. But you can use some general physics textbooks which describe a lots of physical consequences regarding the theory or its application. In fact, some textbooks like "Fundamentals of Physics" or "University Physics" make us curious by asking a question at the very beginning and then only introduce us the theories to solve that question. I think these books will be extremely helpful to you. You have "The Feynman Lectures of Physics" also which provide a deep insight to the theories and Feynman's own viewpoint of understanding.

Answer (score 1):

As an applied physicist, a field which is the bridge between physics and engineering, my work is to apply physical concepts to practical problems.  Sometimes it is in the context of setting up experiments for fundamental physics; other times it is finding solutions to problems.

Though there may be a "magic text book" which answers your specific needs, the usual way to learn is to actually apply the physics taught in the class room to practical problems in a laboratory; the teaching lab is the first place to start, though you can also do basic things at home, or anywhere: inertia, friction, moment arms, static electricity, potential energy, optical diffraction and refraction, reflection and scattering, and the same for acoustics.

The possibilities are literally endless.